# How to make the content of the following table cell scrollable?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, html-table

I have the following table :

[image]

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td>
    Company 1
  </td>
  <td>
    Person 1
  </td>
  <td rowspan="3">
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>        
        <li>Item 5</li>
      </ul>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    Company 2
  </td>
  <td>
    Person 2
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    Company 3
  </td>
  <td>
    Person 3
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q7n167ww/14/

I would like the content of the 3rd column to not expand the height of the table and it's content to be scrollable (with a vertical scroll) :

[image]

The number of rows of the table is not known in advance so it is not possible to set a fixed height for the table or cell. I would like a 100% CSS solution, no JS.

Comment: If you want a 100% CSS solution, I recommend you ditch tables and use floated, styled divs (that way the floated right block could have height 100% and always be the same height as the table, regardless of "rows").

Answer (score 2):

So a way is to put a `div` inside the rowspannig `td`, and directly set its `max-height` CSS value according to the `rowspan` value (rows * coff, see the code).

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td>
    Company 1
  </td>
  <td>
    Person 1
  </td>
  <td class="rowspanning" rowspan="3">
      <div style="max-height:4.5em"> <!-- coeff 1.5 -->
        <ul>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
          <li>Item 4</li>
          <li>...</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then adjust the CSS this way :

```
td
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height:1.5em;
}

td.rowspanning div
{
  width:100%;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  overflow-x:auto;
}

/* Optional : for nice display :) */
td.rowspanning div ul
{
  margin:0 1em 0 1em;
  padding:0 0 0 1em;
}
```

[See Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/q7n167ww/24/). If you need more explanation, you're welcome.

**Edits :**

- Removed unneeded styles
- Put direct styling too
- Replaced `10em` `div` width by `100%`
- Set improved `ul` styling
- Updated fiddle.
- Example with more rows, added a coeff (updated fiddle).

Comment: Try adding much more rows to your jsfiddle example and it wont work anymore.

Comment: I've edited my answer : 3em is for 3 rows. Maybe you can set direct css in the div according to the number of rows ?

Comment: @tigrou, just edited my answer to illustrate direct css styling.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use css for your last col with div inside

html:

```
<table border="1"> 
 <tr>
  <td>A</td>
  <td rowspan="3">
   <div id="col_overflow">
   1<br />
   2<br />
   3<br />
   4<br />
   5
   </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
  <td>B</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>C</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
#col_overflow {
overflow-y:scroll; 
height:5em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div.scrollable {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    margin: 20px;
                    padding: 0;
                    overflow: auto;
                }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q7n167ww/23/

Comment: Could you please post a complete working jsfiddle example ? the link you added is the one from OP.